# Can only program Pro Mini board once then error getsync()

Tags: arduino-pro-mini

I am 100% new to Arduino.  I am using the Pro Mini 328P 3.3v 8mhz board.  I can successfully write to the board once with the Blink program. I set the FTDI to 3.3v jumper. It works.  Then if I try to upload again (I changed the timing on the blink) I get the getsync error.  I tried two boards they both fail after the first upload.  I am using Win 10.

This is the error I see:
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xaf

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the used Arduino IDE settings and how you connect your FTDI (I assume, not FTDL) to the target board?

Comment: `I can successfully write to the board once with the Blink program` ... how do you know this? ... the blink program may have been previously loaded onto the board

Comment: Because I have 5 of these 328P boards and I uploaded another program to one of them and it works monitoring a voltage on a FRSky S6R receiver.  But once I upload a program I can no longer upload to the board.

Comment: https://imgur.com/zSFHVQt
https://imgur.com/zqdw9Td

It's DTR to DTR, TX to RX, RX to TX, VCC to VCC, GND to GND

Comment: Bad link in the previous comment:  IDE screen shot:

https://imgur.com/gallery/zqdw9Td

Comment: Have you reconnected the FTDI adapter? Then it could happen that windows choose a new PORT. In that case you have to reset the port to the new one. I've also heard of others, they had problems with the usb driver of the FTDI mod. Could you look into the device manager to see if the USB device FTDI i still working?

Comment: The COM port has not changed.  (I confirmed in the device manager) I can take a new unprogrammed Mini Pro and it works fine.  I bought a total of 5 of them.  Does the upload wipe the boot loader?

Comment: I got an UNO R3 board.  I was able to take those Pro Mini boards that would not accept a 2nd upload and got them working.  Something on that FTDI board must be wiping the bootloader.